# Default argument in JavaScript caused jshint error

Tags: javascript, jshint

for example, my code below

```
(function ($) {

    window.FOO || (FOO = {});

}(jQuery));
```

caused jshint error:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

Are there any better way to write my above code?

i.e. if `FOO` is not defined in global window scope, init it as `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** From comments:

> I've updated the code above. I want the FOO in the global scope, i.e. window.

For that you can just set `window.FOO` instead:

```
window.FOO = window.FOO || {};
```

Here if `window.FOO` already exists its value will remain unchanged, otherwise `window.FOO` will be set to an empty object.

---

**Old answer:**

You need to declare the variable using `var`:

```
var FOO = window.FOO || {};
```

This will set the `FOO` variable to `window.FOO` if that exists or an empty object if not.

```
var FOO = window.FOO || {};
console.log(FOO);

> Object {}

window.FOO = "Hello, world!";
var FOO = window.FOO || {};
console.log(FOO);

> "Hello, world!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code above. I want the `FOO` in the global scope, i.e. window.

Comment: I've updated to use "window.FOO = window.FOO || {};", but jshint still showing error of "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

Comment: See this script: http://pastebin.com/8x4WJGSh, jshint return error "line 3, col 35, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
", using jshint v2.5.2

Comment: @Ryan because you're not using the code I've given you. You're using `window.FOO || (window.FOO = {});`, *not* `window.FOO = window.FOO || {};`.